# How to display a local link with XML and XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I display a link (with local href address) with XSL and XML, so that it becomes a clickable link?

**My XSLT so far:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Tools">
    <xsl:if test='count(Item)>0'>
      <h3>Tools</h3>
      <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="Item">
        <li>
          <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@Location"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></a>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Binaries ModuleName="Tools">
   <Item Title="Tool1" Location="\\myFolder\myApps\Tool1.jpg"/>
   <Item Title="Tool2" Location="\\myFolder\myApps\Tool2.jpg"/>
</Binaries>
```

**Current result of this:**

```
<a href="%5C%5CmyFolder%5CmyApps%5CTool1.jpg">Tool1</a>
```

which should be rendered as

```
<a href="\\myFolder\myApps\Tool1.jpg">Tool1</a>
```

but instead, the backslash's are missing on my link, so it does not work.

I have a lot of XML files like this, so it would be of need to just change the code in the XSLT if possible.
Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Link does not work, 'cause it's not well formed

Comment: You're missing the closing tag `</xsl:stylesheet>`.

Comment: no it's there in my file, I just missed it here in my sample. I've edited the Sample now.

Comment: Note that Windows platforms also support forward slashes (`/`). If browsing to local files on a local machine is desirable, consider specifying the protocol as well as the path to the file using forward slashes, not backslashes. For example, `file:///myfolder/myapps/Tool1.jpg`. This will entail changing all the XML files, which can be easily accomplished using an advanced editor or GNU command line tools (such as sed).

Comment: Your input XML and XSLT **do not** correspond to the claimed output.  The stylesheet contains a single template matching `<Tools>` elements, and there are no such elements in the input XML.  Therefore, only the default template will match any node, and that will not produce the output presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change in the XSLT should retain the value of `@Location` as is.

```
<a href="{@Location}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
</a>
```

Below is the complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Binaries">
    <xsl:if test='count(Item) > 0'>
        <h3>Tools</h3>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="Item">
                <li>
                    <a href="{@Location}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the shared XML, results in the output below.

```
<h3>Tools</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="\\myFolder\myApps\Tool1.jpg">Tool1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="\\myFolder\myApps\Tool2.jpg">Tool2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```